# How to convert an input to a decimal starting in "0."?

Tags: textbox, type-conversion, double, decimal, c#-3.0

So  I have two textboxes that accepts decimal type input. The first box' value is the left side of a decimal number and the second box should be the left side of the decimal number.

I've tried to divide the second value to 10 to get a value such as "0.1" but if i try to put a two digit number it goes "1.1" instead of "0.11"

```
decimal base1 = Convert.ToDecimal(PressureBase1.Text);
decimal base2 = Convert.ToDecimal(PressureBase2.Text)/10;

string baseValue = (base1 +  base2).ToString("0.0");
```

so if my first textbox input is  "1"
and my second textbox input is "0.32"

my baseValue should be "1.32"
but i got "4.2"

Answer (score 0):

U can just add **0.** in the beginning of the text and convert it to decimal afterwards.

```
decimal base1 = Convert.ToDecimal(PressureBase1.Text);
string updatePressureBase2 = "0."+PressureBase2.Text;
decimal base2 = Convert.ToDecimal(updatePressureBase2);
string baseValue = (base1 +  base2).ToString("0.00");
```

Comment: I still get the same result

Comment: try this  decimal base2 = Convert.ToDecimal(PressureBase2.Text)/100;

Comment: It works though there's a zero before the value. what if i have a 6 digit decimal

Comment: I have update the answer. U can check on it and try.